# Why the exceptional divisor of blowup of $\{x^2+yt=0\}$ has multiplicity one (but not two)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be the affine surface $\{x^2+yt=0\}\subseteq \mathbb C^3$, then $X$ has an $A_1$ singularity at $0$. Consider $X$ as a family of curves via the projection to the last coordiate $$\pi:X\to \mathbb C, (x,y,t)\mapsto t.$$

Let $\sigma:\tilde{X}\to X$ be the blowup of $X$ at $0$ with exceptional divisor $E$, then it is claimed in Harris-Morrison's *Moduli of Curves*, page 133, that the exceptional divisor $E$ has multiplicity *one*.

**Does the multiplicity means the order of vanishing of $(\sigma\circ\pi)^*(t)$ on the component $E$? How to obtain $E$ has multiplicity one?**

Here is [another example in Harris-Morrison](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/478206), where the family is $y^2-x^3-t=0$ and it is shown that exceptional divisor of blowup acquires with multiplicity *two*. (Note the major difference between two examples is the smoothness of the original total space.)

I was imitating its computation to work in my case: Blowup $0\in \mathbb C^3$ and get $W\subseteq \mathbb C^3\times \mathbb P^2_{[\alpha,\beta,\gamma]}$ with equations
$$x\beta=y\alpha,x\gamma=t\alpha,y\gamma=t\beta.$$

Then $\tilde{X}\subset W$ is the strict transform of this blowup and $E$ is the conic $\{\alpha^2+\beta\gamma=0\}\subseteq \mathbb P^2_{[\alpha,\beta,\gamma]}$. By setting $\gamma=1$, we have affine equation of $\tilde{X}$ $$x=t\alpha, \ y=t\beta, \ t^2(\alpha^2+\beta)=0.$$

To me, the appearance of the $t^2$ means the vanishing order of $t$ on exceptional $E$ has order *two*.

This contradicts the conclusion in the book. Am I missing something?

**Edited**: The picture attached below is a piece from page 133 of *Moduli of curves*, and the last sentence is where I am trying to understand:
[image: Muduli of Curves]

Comment: Dear @KReiser: I think the authors just mean blow up at the singular point, since we eventually want the total space $\tilde{X}$ to be smooth. But on the other hand, if we blowup the codimension locus $\{t=0\}$, what I get is an affine equation $x^2+vt^2=0$, so the resulting total space is not normal.

Comment: Oops, what I wrote there is neither correct nor what I intended to write (nor is what I intended to write correct). I'll delete that comment and see if I can't say something that's somewhat correct.

Comment: I agree with your assessment that the exceptional divisor over the blowup at the origin has multiplicity two. If this is not a typo, then I think more context is required to understand this conflict. Can you add more details/context about where this construction appears and what's supposed to be happening?

Comment: @KReiser: I added a page from Harris-Morrison. Actually, I have consulted an expert about this, and I was told something even more general should be true: i.e., say, if $\pi:X\to \mathbb C$ is a flat family with total space $X$ having an ordinary node at $p\in X_0=\pi^{-1}(0)$, but $X_0$ is smooth, then the desingularization of $X$ has exceptional divisor multiplicity _one_. I was told that $X$ being singular is a crucial point. So I thought perhaps both of us are missing something.

Comment: I don't think this fact applies here: in this case, $X_0$ is not smooth, it's cut out by the ideal $(x^2-yt,t)=(x^2,t)$. I'll look at the text and see if I can find something worth saying.

Comment: @KReiser Sorry, I was not being precise here, I mean $(X_0)_{red}$ being smooth.

Comment: Your computation answers a different question --- it shows that the full transform of $X$ in the blowup of $\mathbb{C}^3$ is the union of its strict transform (given by the equation $\alpha^2 + \beta = 0$ in this chart) and the exceptional divisor with multiplicity 2. Now consider the strict transform (it is equal to the blowup of $X$). In this chart it is just $$\mathbb{C}^2$ with coordinates $(\alpha,t)$, the fiber over $0$ is given by $t = 0$, so it has multiplicity 1.

Comment: @Sasha Thanks for your help! I appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sasha's already covered this in the comments, but I want to make what was said there a little more explicit. The problem here is that the blowup that has been computed (I made this mistake too!) was the blowup of a point inside $\Bbb A^3$, not a point inside $X$.

To be precise, if one has $Z\subset Y\subset X$ a chain of closed subvarieties, we computed $Bl_Z X$ and looked at the total transform of $Y$, that is, the preimage of $Y$ under the map $\pi:Bl_Z X\to X$. Instead, what one should do to find the blowup $Bl_Z Y$ is to consider the *strict transform* of $Y$ in $Bl_Z X$. See for instance [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823338/strict-transform-of-blow-up), remark 9.11 in [Gathmann's notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2019/alggeom-2019.pdf), Hartshorne examples I.4.9.1 and II.7.15.1, etc.

In our case, the blowup of $X$ at $0$ is the strict transform of $X$ under the blowup of $\Bbb A^3$ at zero. The strict transform is covered by three charts $\alpha=1$, $\beta=1$, and $\gamma=1$ which have coordinate algebras $k[x,\beta,\gamma]/(1+\beta\gamma)$, $k[\alpha,y,\gamma]/(\alpha^2+\gamma)$, and $k[\alpha,\beta,t]/(\alpha^2+\beta)$ respectively. The exceptional divisor in each of these patches is just given by taking the closed subschemes associated to $x=0$, $y=0$, and $t=0$, respectively, and the subschemes we get this way are of multiplicity one.

Comment: Dear KReiser, thanks for your detailed explanation. I used your method to compute the multipiclity of exceptional divisor $E$ in the blowup of $y^2-x^3-t=0$: on chart $\beta=1$, the equation becomes $y(y-\alpha^3 y^2-\gamma)$, where the $y$ factor corresponds to the $\mathbb P^2$ with multiplicity one and the other factor is strict transform which has coordinate algebra $k[y,\alpha,\gamma]/(y-\alpha^3 y^2-\gamma)$, so $\gamma=0$ vanishes on $y=0$ with multiplicity one, but $t=\gamma y$, so $t$ vanishes on $y=0$ with multiplcity two, so $E$ has multiplcity two. Do you agree with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but here are two *evidence* that I came up with to explain the multiplicity one issue. We use the same notation  $X=\{x^2+yt=0\}$ and $\tilde{X}$ the blowup with exceptional divisor $E$.

**Evidence 1**: I can choose a holomorphic path $P$ on $\tilde{X}$ where the resetriction to $P$ of pullback of $t$ vanishes simply on $E$: Explicitly, in the affine chart $\gamma=1$, then $\tilde{X}$ is defined by the equation $\{\alpha^2+\beta=0\}\subseteq \mathbb C^3_{[\alpha,\beta,t]}$ with $\pi\circ\sigma$ the projection to the last coordinate. The path is given by $[1,-1,t]$.

**Evidence 2**: We can identify $X$ with the quotient $\mathbb C^2/\mathbb Z_2$ with action given by $$(u,v)\mapsto (-u,-v).$$
On the ring level, $u^2, v^2, uv$ generates the invariant subring and the quotient  $f:\mathbb C^2\to X$ is by setting $t=u^2,y=-v^2,x=uv$.

It induces $\mathbb Z_2$-action on the blowup $Bl_0\mathbb C^2$ fixing the exceptional divisor $D=p^{-1}(0)$. So there is a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Bl_0\mathbb C^2 @>\tilde{f}>> \tilde{X}\\
@VpVV @V{\sigma}VV\\
\mathbb C^2  @>f>> X
\end{CD}
with $\tilde{f}$ a double cover branched along the smooth divisor $E$. **So the local equation of $E$ in $\tilde{X}$ pullback under $\tilde{f}$ to the square of local equation on $D$ in $Bl_0\mathbb C^2$.**

Since $p^*(u)$ vanishes simply on $D$, one has $$\tilde{f}^*\circ\sigma^*(t)=p^*f^*(t)=p^*(u^2)$$ vanishes to the order two on $D$. So $\sigma^*(t)$ vanishes to the order one on $E$ by the highlighted sentence. Namely, $E$ has multiplicity one.

**Do you agree with these? Also, these approaches are more or less indirect, but what is a standard approach to find multiplicity on the exceptional divisor? And why my approach in the question direct to a different answer?**

I appreciate any comments and suggestions.

Comment: could you loose a few words on why the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action on $\mathbb{C}^2$ lifts to an action on $Bl_0\mathbb C^2$? It seems to be possible to lift the action to $Bl_0\mathbb C^2$ as a set-action, but I assume you mean there an action on $Bl_0\mathbb C^2$ as scheme, not just a set.